# How config Exim4 to accept only authenticated sender

Tags: exim, spoofing

How can I setup Exim to accept only authenticated email from managed domain address?
I'm receiving spoofed email.. from myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can make a reasonable assumption that "real you" will never submit the message from the external MTA. So you can use the next ACL at the RCPT stage:

```
deny 
  sender_domains = +local_domains
  hosts          = !+relay_from_hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a suitable SPF record in your DNS that designates which hosts may send mail from your domain, and configure your mail host to check those SPF records.